# How do I convert an integer to a binary in Erlang?

Tags: list, erlang, integer

I am trying to make an integer into a binary:

```
543 = <<"543">>
```

How can I do this without

```
integer_to_list(list_to_binary(K)).
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be list_to_binary(integer_to_list(Int))?

Comment: I think what he meant is that generating fully-functional-string in erlang takes too much mem (becuase its linked list of characters, so with each letter it consumes extra 32-bit or 64-bit for pointer to next char in string)

Comment: I highly doubt the erlang devs made strings a linked list of chars.  I have not checked myself but i cant imagine such an inefficient use of linked list in production.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to convert 543 to <<"543">> I don't think you can find something faster than:

```
1> list_to_binary(integer_to_list(543)).
<<"543">>
```

Because in this case both functions implemented in C.

If you want to convert integer to the smallest possible binary representation you can use [binary:encode_unsigned](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html#encode_unsigned-1) function from the new [binary](http://erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html) module like this:

```
1> binary:encode_unsigned(543).
<<2,31>>
2> binary:encode_unsigned(543, little).
<<31,2>>
```

Answer (score 19):

For current readers, this is now implemented in R16, see http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#integer_to_binary-1

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like

```
6> A = 12345.                       
12345
7> B = <<A:32>>.
<<0,0,48,57>>
```

But this requires you to know the maximum number of bits in advance.

Comment: Good Idea, but what if I don't know.  Isn't there a binary option without the colon to do it.  I tried _ didn't work.

Comment: You can always do the conversion in steps. (A rem 4294967296) for each 32 bits and loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question because I wanted the "print representation" of a binary written as an integer. This is how you do that:

```
1> integer_to_list(543, 2).
"1000011111"
```

The second argument is the base you want, and it accepts all the way up to 36 (go to Wikipedia and read about base36 encoding now).