# Erlang: How to convert erlang date to binary?

Tags: date, erlang, tuples, binaries

I have the following function that returns current date:

```
7> {Y,M,D}=erlang:date().
{2014,11,18}
```

Now I need to have a binary with these values inside like this:

```
<<"20141118">>
```

I have tried

```
15> S= [Y,M,D].
[2014,11,18]
16> list_to_binary(S).
** exception error: bad argument
 in function  list_to_binary/1
    called as list_to_binary([2014,11,18])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
9> list_to_binary(lists:map(fun erlang:integer_to_list/1, [Y, M, D])).
<<"20141118">>
```

Or like this, which is equivalent but not really practical for larger lists:

```
10> list_to_binary([integer_to_list(Y), integer_to_list(M), integer_to_list(D)]).
<<"20141118">>
```

Comment: consider to use `integer_to_binary/1`, would be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function, based on the answers to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4010713/2088822), and [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600642/2088822).

```
date_to_binary() ->
    {Y,M,D} = erlang:date(),
    BinY = list_to_binary(integer_to_list(Y)),
    BinM = list_to_binary(integer_to_list(M)),
    BinD = list_to_binary(integer_to_list(D)),
    <<BinY/binary, BinM/binary, BinD/binary>>.
```

This may not be the most efficient method, but it is probably the most explicit step by step conversion available out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

```
{Y,M,D}=erlang:date().
list_to_binary( io_lib:format("~p~p~p", [Y,M,D]) ).
```

The output is `<<"20141119">>`.

You can try this method.

Answer (score 0):

You should add separators in your binary or at least format it otherwise you will not be able to make the difference between 2014/12/09 and 2014/01/29 with the binary <<"2014129">>.
You could use:

```
list_to_binary(io_lib:format("~4w~2w~2w", [Y,M,D])).  % which will add space when necessary
```

Or if you only want to store the information you can store each element as a 16 bit binary:

```
lists:foldr(fun(X,Acc) -> <<X:16,Acc/binary>> end,<<>>,[Y,M,D]). % the result is less friendly to read but easier to manipulate.
```

Result:

```
1> list_to_binary(io_lib:format("~4w~2w~2w",[2014,1,11])).   
<<"2014 111">>
2> lists:foldr(fun(X,Acc) -> <<X:16,Acc/binary>> end,<<>>,[2014,1,11]).
<<7,222,0,1,0,11>>
3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but why not:

Another single line option using [qdate](http://github.com/choptastic/qdate) (a project of mine):

```
qdate:to_string(<<"Ymd">>, {erlang:date(), {0,0,0}}).
```

`qdate:to_string`'s formatting option follows PHP's `date()` function formatting conventions. The addition of {0,0,0} is necessary because a three-tuple is treated as an erlang timestamp (`now()` format) while a two-tuple of three-tuples (ex: `{{2015, 9, 30}, {15, 54, 39}}`) is needed for it to identify a date format.